# Rails5 migration: can't quote Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I try to migrate my app from Rails 4 to Rails 5
Here is my migration:

```
class AddRevealedIdsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :revealed_ids, :text, default: []
  end
end
```

And model:

```
serialize :revealed_ids
```

It worked perfectly in Rails 4, now I have an error:

```
== 20160416214334 AddRevealedIdsToUser: migrating =============================
-- add_column(:users, :revealed_ids, :text, {:default=>[]})
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

can't quote Array
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:177:in `_quote'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/quoting.rb:96:in `_quote'
```

how to solve?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try adding `array:true` to your migration.

```
add_column :users, :revealed_ids, :text, default: [], array:true
```

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 35):

As temporary solution I serialize it manually.

```
add_column :users, :revealed_ids, :text, default: [].to_yaml
```

Opened an issue in Rails repository.

Answer (score 3):

I also want to add for anyone who is hitting the head on the wall with this in their rails app. The fix for me was switching to a Postgres database versus a SQLite database. Postgres can handle more advanced data structures.

After switching to a Postgres database I was able to run the below code with my migration with no errors.

```
add_column :users, :revealed_ids, :text, default: [], array:true
```